# How to insert datas to excel sheet in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

am new to  php and i have one task  first retrieve the data from mysql and insert those data's  in  excel sheet to their corresponding fields.And i did  retrieve the data and i dont know how  to insert those datas in excel sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into this. [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score -1):

First set Excel headers:

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=xls_file_".date("Ymd").".xls");
```

Then just output a ordinary HTML table `<table><tr><td>some_data_01</td><td>some_data_02</td>... ...</table>` - whatever you need there in your Excel.

The result will be an Excel file.